# WPF ToolTip: Fade In/Out. Is it a good idea to fix the ToolTip position?

Tags: wpf, tooltip

I want to fade in/out a ToolTip how can I achieve that?

Also, I wonder if its a good idea to fix the position of the ToolTip? eg. always at bottom? I guess the ToolTip may go off screen? And suppose I want to do that, how can I do that? Position the ToolTip a fixed position relative to the parent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The position is relative to the parent unless you specify otherwise. If you want it to display somewhere else you can use

```
<TextBox ToolTipService.PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=displayToolTipHere}">
```

To specify the position you use Placement. Either ToolTipService.Placement in TextBox or Placement inside the ToolTip like in my example below. I don't think ToolTip has any built in "fade in/fade out" but you can use an animation. Don't think you can make it fade out though since it instantly closes once the mouse leaves the Control. If you want a fade out effect you should probably use a Popup instead.

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip Placement="Bottom"
                 Content="Some ToolTip Content">
            <ToolTip.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ToolTip.Opened">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard TargetProperty="Opacity">
                            <DoubleAnimation From="0.0" To="1.0" Duration="0:0:2" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </ToolTip.Triggers>
        </ToolTip>
    </TextBox.ToolTip>
</TextBox>
```